# Nikon d7100 top lcd ligh turns on when flash is fired

Tags: nikon, flash, light, display, nikon-d7100

Today while shooting I noticed, that when I use an external flash, the top LCD light turns on. I turned it off, by clicking to the bulb icon as usually, and when I fired again, it turned on once again.
I've checked all the settings I just can't find anything related to this problem.

P.S.
I've only noticed this now, shooting whit the flash on the hot shoe. The other day I was shooting whit a remote trigger on my camera and I don't really remember having this issue.